# Axis ordering in ggplot2 is not taken into account

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, axis, heatmap

I have a data frame `dataInitial` comprising three numeric columns.
`Axis1`, `Axis2` and `Value`.

Here is my code for the heatmap graph :

```
theplot <- ggplot(dataInitial, aes(as.factor(Axis1), as.factor(Axis2), group=Axis2))
theplot <- theplot + geom_tile(aes(fill = Value))
theplot <- theplot + geom_text(aes(fill = Value, label = round(Value, 1)))
theplot <- theplot + scale_x_discrete(breaks=sort(unique(dataInitial$Axis1),TRUE))
theplot <- theplot + scale_y_discrete(breaks=sort(unique(dataInitial$Axis2),TRUE))
theplot <- theplot + scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") 
theplot <- theplot + theme_bw()
```

I would like my axis to be sorted in descending order but ggplot2 doesn't seem to take my sorting into account (cf image below)

[image: The Plot]

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Try `rev`: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Axes_%28ggplot2%29/#changing-the-order-of-items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why (Maybe someone can post a more detailed answer as to why that works) but replacing `breaks` by `limits` in the code above works great.
Thanks @Phil for the hint.